# How does looking up into a hash work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

How does Ruby look for keys in a hash? I thought that as soon as it finds a key inside a hash, it returns its value without evaluating the other key/value pairs? But I guess I am wrong. 
Eg,

```
test = {"a" => 10, "b" => 20, "c" => 30, "d" => 1/0}
```

now if i do `test["a"]`, it returns error because of d's infinite value, if i remove "d", it works fine(which means it checks all the key/value pairs even if it finds a match in the first key). So if i search for a key in a really large hash, does Ruby evaluate every key/value for validity before returning the value for that particular hash? If that is the case, is there a way to break out of the hash as soon as it finds the key?

**UPDATE**
Just to clarify, I am trying to understand how it works in Ruby. So, for eg, if i have a hash with 500 key/value pairs(all valid not like 1/0), and lets say "a" is the first key. So if i do test["a"] on that large hash, does Ruby load all the key/value pairs in memory under the hood  or just break out after it finds the key "a"?

Comment: I get an error trying to run your initialization. 1/0 is evaluated at hash creation time...
Which version of ruby are you using ?

Comment: irb(main):001:0> test = {"a" => 10, "b" => 20, "c" => 30, "d" => 1/0}
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
 from (irb):1:in `/'
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/za/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: same here , it threw an exception.. which is expected.

Comment: @BA which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I am using Ruby version 2.2.4 that comes with Railsinstaller.

Comment: Same version here, and same errors as above, both in irb and plain interpreter. Can you share the exact code you executed?

Comment: yeah correct, that is what i am trying to say. Is it possible to just exit after a match is found? lets say "d" => 100, then when i do test["a"] it will return 10, but i assume it goes through all those key/value pairs right, or does it just break out after it finds the value for the key "a"?

Comment: @B A i think it is best to change the question by getting rid of the 1/0 hash value .... I just do not see the point of experimening  with some infinite value.

Comment: @z_- just clarified the question a bit. I just wanted to understand how it works.

Comment: I understand what you mean, @BA. The point here is that you insist the error occurs when accessing the hash and many people (including me) say the error occurs when creating the hash. When you initialize a hash Ruby has to initialize each pair of `key: value`. And when this occurs, the error happens. So, all the question has no sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting occurs when ruby is creating the hash, not while accessing it - inserting the values into the hash clearly requires evaluating them.

There is no "loading" going on when fetching a value from a hash: the entirety of the hash is always in memory. A full explanation of hash tables is a bit out of scope but in a nutshell a hash works by hashing the key from which ruby derives which of the hashes buckets should contain the value. That bucket is then searched and the value is returned if the key is found.